# Jmeter : getting 401 error

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Does any one knows how to solve it with regular expression? here  i am putting screen shot with valid access token and error response token.
thanks in advance.

Valid response token

[image]

invalid response token

[image]

and Regular expression exctracter
[image]

it is fine if you guys have any other solution for this unauthorized access thing.

Comment: Add text of responses , and do you need regular expression for success/failed or both?

Comment: only success. I have try to add responses but failed. can you help you with a query ?

Comment: what you need to find only access_token? did you try to find similar questions? for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46690181/the-reference-value-not-send-along-with-request-headers-in-jmeter

Comment: i have tried this. http://prntscr.com/hj83au  , http://prntscr.com/hj83f7 but it is not working , still facing 401 error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a child of the `authserver` request and configure it as follows:

   - Variable Names: anything meaningful, i.e. `token`
   - JSON Path expressions: `$.access_token`
2. Add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) as a child of the `student` request and configure it to send `Authorization` header with the value of `Bearer ${token}`

Going forward you can go for an alternative way of recording a JMeter test which is capable of exporting the recorded requests in SmartJMX mode with automatic correlation of dynamic parameters applied so you will be able to save your time for more creative work. See [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for more details.